# how to set custom 404 page for EC2 php instance?

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-404

I'm running a PHP website and would like to set `.htaccess` to point 404 errors to a custom `404.php` page. Inside `.htaccess` I have:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Both `.htaccess` and `404.php` is in `/var/www/html` directory.

What is wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? We won't be able to help you if you don't give us details.

Comment: i'm getting the default apache Not Found message page. I would like to send the page to a custom 404.php page instead.

Comment: please provide some more details such as where apache's root directory are, versions, troubleshooting you've already done etc.

Comment: my apache should be in /etc/httpd/conf  version is 2.2.29. i did try putting .htaccess in several directories but it doesn't work.